# C# .NET Core SQL Server Connectivity

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string

Within my startup, I load a set of database connection strings from the appsettings.json file. The connection strings look as follows

"CoreConnectionString": "Server=localhost; Database=DBCore; Uid=someUserName; Pwd=somePW",
"IdentityConnectionString": "Server=localhost; Database=DBAuth; Uid=someUserName; Pwd=somePW"

What is the best way to encrypt this information so I don't show the actual user name and password?

Comment: encrypt it where? on development? on runtime? if runtime, where are you running your app? cloud? Please be more specific of what you're asking for. where is that you don't want to show the username and the password?

Comment: The appsettings file was never meant for secret configurations. For local development you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=linux#secret-manager

If you are needing them in a deployed environment, you should really look into external secret stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two suggestions to not expose your DB Password and Conn Strings:

1. Use a secret file in your computer, apart from your Solution. In Visual Studio 2022 you can do it [by clicking your project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLFey.png). Just throw your connections strings there like in AppSettings.json.

- Pro: Easy to use
- Con: You can't deply it with your project or store it at github

2. Use Azure Key Valut to store all connection strings. Read [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service) from Microsoft if it's your way to go.

- Pro: No need for local files. Cloud stored Keys.
- Con: Need a bot more configuration in your project and an Azure account.